# how to use one post method two times in differerent views function in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

I have a post method templates(i.e. foo_form.html) and two function(foo1,foo2) in views.py where I want to use post value.

My foo_form.html is here

```
<html>{% load i18n %}
  <head>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name= "month"> </input>
    <input type="text" name= "year"> </input>
    <input type="submit" value="view">
   </form>
```

In foo1 function I need do some task along with validate month & year and redirect to security_check page where I need to check if he right person to see that page.

Now if he passes the check task then redirect to foo2 function. In foo2 function I have to use month & year> my forms.py is like this

```
class month_Form(forms.Form):
  Month = forms.IntegerField()
  Year = forms.IntegerField()
```

My views.py is like this

```
def foo1(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    month_form = month_Form(request.POST)
    if pay_form.is_valid():
        # do some task
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/security_check/')
  return render(request, 'foo_form.html', {})

def foo2(request):
  month_form1 = month_Form(request.POST) # I cann't get whether request.method == 'POST': should be there or not?
  month_no = request.POST.get('Month',False)
  # unable to retrieve month_no 
  # and in debug method is showing "GET"
```

My /security_check/ function is like this

```
def security_check(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    month_form = month_Form(request.POST)
    if pay_form.is_valid():
      # validated weather he has the permission to go to foo2
      #redirect to foo2
  #render to security_check_form.html(this is a security que form html)
```

I am using Django 1.6. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the `/security_check/` URL supposed to be routed to your `foo2` view in your example? It is very unclear how your example is expected to work.

Comment: No, no /security_check/ is another function

Comment: How do you redirect to foo2?

Comment: return HttpResponseRedirect('/foo2/')

Comment: And you expected that this request will be with POST method? Or you fill up the form of `foo2` and send it to your view?

Comment: A potential solution would be to pull out the logic from `foo2` into a re-usable function, then rather returning an HttpResponseRedirect to it you would call the new function. This would also be faster from the user's perspective since you wouldn't be redirecting them around.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh I got it from Django [doc.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test)

I can create security_check function view, Where I can customize my own form(like @login required() )

```
def foo1(request):
   if request.method==POST:
     #retrieve value in POST method 
     #call foo2
     return render (request,destination.html{variables})
   return render(request, 'foo_form.html', {}) 

@user_passes_test(security_check[, login_url=None])
def foo2(postdatas):
  #do some task
  # return tapule on the basis of requirement
```